# Manipulate self object in class

Tags: python, class, self

i implement a linked list in Python for my student and particulary a simply version of the "reverse" method ...

This a version that works :

```
class SimpleList:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    if len(args) == 0:
      self.__cell = None
    elif len(args) == 2:
      if isinstance(args[1], SimpleList):
        self.__cell = (args[0], args[1])
      else:
        print("Erreur 2")
    else:
      print("Erreur 3")

  def car(self):
    if not self.isNull():
      return self.__cell[0]
    print("Erreur 4")

  def cdr(self):
    if not self.isNull():
      return self.__cell[1]
    print("Erreur 5")

  def isNull(self):
    return self.__cell == None

  def __repr__(self):
    if self.isNull():
      return '()'
    else:
      return '(' + repr(self.car()) + ',' + repr(self.cdr()) + ')'
      
  def nbrElement(self):
    num = 0
    tab = self
    while not(tab.isNull()):
      num = num+1
      tab = tab.cdr()
    return num

      
  def reverse(self):
    num=self.nbrElement()-1
    pCourant = SimpleList(self.car(),SimpleList())
    tab = self.cdr()
    for i in range(0,num-1):
      tabTmp = tab
      tab = tab.cdr()
      tabTmp.__cell = (tabTmp.car(),pCourant)
      pCourant= tabTmp
    self.__cell = neww = (tab.car(),pCourant)
```

and the code to execute :

```
slA = SimpleList(10,SimpleList(9,SimpleList(8,SimpleList(7,SimpleList(6,SimpleList(5,SimpleList(4,SimpleList())))))))
print(slA)
slA.reverse()
print(slA)
```

but i need to redefine the new tail object

I try to do it only with "swap" the inner link :

```
  def reverse(self):
    num=self.nbrElement()-1
    pCourant = SimpleList()
    tab = self
    for i in range(0,num-1):
      tabTmp = tab
      tab = tab.cdr()
      tabTmp.__cell = (tabTmp.car(),pCourant)
      pCourant= tabTmp
    self.__cell = neww = (tab.car(),pCourant)
```

There is a personn that can explain me this ???
Thanks for your help

---

Update :

```
  def reverse(self):
    num=self.nbrElement()-1
    pCourant = SimpleList()
    tab = self
    for i in range(0,num):
      tabTmp = tab
      tab = tab.cdr()
      tabTmp.__cell = (tabTmp.car(),pCourant)
      pCourant= tabTmp
    neww = SimpleList(tab.car(),pCourant)
    print(neww)
    print(neww)
    self.__cell = neww.__cell
slA = SimpleList(10,SimpleList(9,SimpleList(8,SimpleList())))
slA.reverse()

print(slA.cdr().cdr().car())
print(slA)
```

Is notfor optimize my code ... But for understand, the "inner logic" of Python :

- `print(new)` works well
- a `print(slA)` do a "maximum recursion depth"
- the penultimate display offer 8 but normally would display 10

Thanks for all

Comment: Explain what exactly?

Comment: By the way, why do you bother with a `__cell` tuple when something like `self.value`, `self.next` would be much clearer?

Comment: (Also, using `print`s for error "handling"?)

Comment: I update my post .. Thanks for your attention

Comment: "print(slA) do a "maximum recursion depth"" Without seeing the traceback, I'd divine that your reversing algorithm manages to create a loop in the linked list, and since your `repr` implementation is recursive...

Comment: Ok, but why print(neww) don't show the recursive error and present the correct "reverse list"
i affect "self.__cell = neww.__cell" and out of the class and method, the recursiv error appaer?
I don't know about "traceback", i'll further this point
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm still in the process of drinking my first cup of coffee, here's a simpler reimplementation.

(The `__slots__` thing is a pre-optimization; you can elide it if you like.)

```
class ListCell:
    __slots__ = ("value", "next")

    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

    def __repr__(self):
        if not self.next:
            return f"({self.value!r})"
        else:
            return f"({self.value!r},{self.next!r})"

    def reverse(self):
        prev = next = None
        curr = self
        while curr:
            next = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = next
        return prev  # Return new head

    @classmethod
    def from_iterable(cls, items):
        head = tail = None
        for item in items:
            if head is None:
                head = tail = cls(item)
            else:
                tail.next = cls(item)
                tail = tail.next
        return head


lc = ListCell.from_iterable([1, 2, 4, 8])
print(lc)
lc = lc.reverse()
print(lc)
```

This prints out

```
(1,(2,(4,(8))))
(8,(4,(2,(1))))
```

Comment: Very short, very clean ... I have to work about it to understand more Python
But for eduction propose (high school student that begin Python), internal usage of Python's class are a little hard
Thanks

Comment: @Tom High school students beginning Python shouldn't be implementing linked lists in my opinion. Python comes with perfectly fine regular lists.

Comment: In French program for K12 that take new "option informatic", we have to use Python ... Linked list is a theory point of programm and i need to implement it in PYthon
We go to further class a little more away in the year ... but not so deeply
Thanks for your help